# python override getLogger()

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

In my `<my_module_name>` module I have this:

```
import logging
import my_module_name.log
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This works fine, but I would like to be able to override logging.getLogger() in /log.py so I can use:

```
import my_module_name.log
log = my_module_name.log.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: There are two getLogger functions one is at module level which you are using. Second is at class level which is part of logging.Manager class. Which one you want to override?. I guess you don't want to override module level getLogger because its just a utility function and you won't be able to do much with it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I like to have all logging defined in a single file. making it harder to do local logging config. Any best practice on this would be great. Found a local config deep down in a class, which would have been prevented if `import logging` was omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options if you want to have a single configuration file. There are ini file based config, dict config based config and code based config. I will explain dict based config here.

define logging conf in some file.

```
logging_config = dict(
    version = 1,
    formatters = {
        'f': {'format':
              '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'}
        },
    handlers = {
        'h': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
              'formatter': 'f',
              'level': logging.DEBUG}
        },
    root = {
        'handlers': ['h'],
        'level': logging.DEBUG,
        },
)
```

Then when you want to log something in your code just instantiate a logger object.

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig
import logging_config   # defined above so import accordingly
dictConfig(logging_config)

logger = logging.getLogger()  # you have a logger ready. Use it to log something
logger.debug("Its a log")
```

Comment: can we add custom field in this?